# Need help in Alloy

Tags: alloy

This is an example of Alloy that I found I want to make it with 3 predicates, 3 facts, 3 objects and 3 assertions, can someone please help me? I am very new in Alloy and need some immediate help.

```
abstract sig Color {}

one sig Red,Yellow,Green extends Color {}

sig Light {
color: Color
}

sig Junction {
lights : set Light
}

fun count[j:Junction, c:Color] : Int { 
#{x:Light | x in j.lights and x.color=c}
}

// This is just for realism, make sure each light belongs to exactly one junction
fact {
Light = Junction.lights
no x,y:Junction | x!=y and some x.lights & y.lights
Light = Junction.lights
no y,x:Junction | y!=x and some y.lights & x.lights

}

pred mostly[j:Junction, c:Color] {
no cc:Color | cc!=c and count[j,cc]>=count[j,c]
}

run{
    some j:Junction | mostly[j,Red]
} for 10 Light, 2 Junction, 10 int`
```

Answer (score 0):

In Alloy, you can only provide a scope for the number of objects (atoms) of each sig in your model.  Predicates, functions, and assertions you write explicitly in your model, they are not "expanded" by the Alloy Analyzer in any way, and they cannot be quantified over, so providing a separate scope for them would not make sense.